# NSTextField connect to NSMenuItem with KeyEquivalent

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, xib

What's the best practice to connect a menuItem to a textfield/searchfield. I would like to offer the users the ability using the shortcut Command F for focusing the searchfield.

[image: customu menu with standard find Submenu]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the way to do this now (since `becomeFirstResponder` isn't recommended) is to link the menu item action to a custom method that tells the window to make your search field the first responder.